# NuGet Server unable to find NuGet.Core DLL

Tags: nuget

I've been trying to get a local version of the NuGet server up and running. I've created an empty website and installed the NuGet server package through NuGet in VS2010. When I run it, I get the 'main' page but when clicking through to the packages feed I get this:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Core,
>   Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack
>   trace is:
>
> at NuGet.Server.DataServices.Packages.CreateDataSource() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateDataSourceInstance() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The version of Nuget.Core that the package manager pulled down is 1.4.20615.9012. I can't see any references to 1.4.0.0 anywhere in the solution.

I tried adding an assembly binding redirect to handle this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NuGet.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.0.0" newVersion="1.4.20615.9012"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

but that just changes the error to be

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Core,
>   Version=1.4.20615.9012, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'. See server logs for
>   more details.

The DLL is definitely in the bin folder and is that version. I've tried changing the reference's "Specific Version" property to False but this doesn't make any difference.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I could try next?

---

Update

On picking through the project file, I found this:

```
<Reference Include="NuGet.Core, Version=1.4.20609.9012, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\NuGet.Core.1.4.20615.9012\lib\net40\NuGet.Core.dll</HintPath>
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

The 1.4.20609.9012 doesn't seem to match anything so I'm not sure where that's coming from. But, updating my binding to this seems to work:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NuGet.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.0.0" newVersion="1.4.20609.9012"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Although, to be honest, I've got it working through luck and I'm not really sure why this fixes it. Any ideas would be very much welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed now. If it isn't please file a bug on http://nuget.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

just a little insight into this as I came across the problem before as well and fixed it similarly to yourself - although mine occurred where I have multiple .sln files and projects and through the Nuget package downloads the bindings became completely wrong. it started referencing versions I don't use and didn't have and all the bindings were mucked up. basically the simple solution is to re-write your own bindings and check you remove (hidden files too), if you have any, references to the other binding versions anywhere that could affect your project. sadly this occurs in my opinion where my EF was trying to be too clever and writing and referencing the wrong bindings, although updating Nuget packages didnt help either but im glad you got your solution. if anyone does have any problems like this simply start by checking your references, versions and bindings.